# GLIBC 2.4 needed for make under Debian 7.5

Tags: linux, gcc, debian

I am compiling a product under Debian 7.5. During compiling using makefile, I incur in an error :

undefined reference to `memcpy@GLIBC_2.14'

In my system it is installed libc6_2.13. 
I am aware that that component cannot be upgraded painlessly, but I'd like to understand if I can have the 2.14 concurrent with it just for this task, then I won't need it anymore. I have looked for a solution since yesterday, but i am wandering.

I need to understand if it is possible or not to use GLIBC 2.14 on my linux version just for a one shot compiling, without damaging it, or if I can

Notes: I cannot change system distro.

Comment: What you are asking is a bit complicated. But what program is failing with this undefined reference (I doubt it is `make` itself) and how did you install it? If glibc and that program are provided by debian, it should have prevented you from installing incompatible versions.

Comment: No, the program is of third party. I solved compiling it under a Ubuntu or Jessie (unstable). Otherwise I think I could have downloaded and locally compiled in a folder GLIBC 2.4, then link to it when compiling using gcc.